# Need ideas to avoid draggable jqueryui issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, iframe

Two programs:

-one has a draggable div with an iframe inside.

```
<head>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />

<script>
$(function() {
    $( "#draggable" ).draggable();
});
</script>

<style>
#draggable { width: 1500px; height: 300px; }
</style>

</head>

<body>
    <div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content" style="background:#ccc">
        <p>Drag me around</p>
        <iframe src="test.php" style="background:#eee;width:100%;height:240px;" frameborder='0' ></iframe>
    </div>
</body>
```

-the other, the iframe program

```
<body>
<div onclick="alert('Clicked here')">Just a test with an input</div>
<input type="text" id="txtid">
</body>
```

**Scenario**: I click the mouse button inside the div to start dragging, and drag the mouse quickly from the div to inside the iframe. I lost the draggable capability (Its ok, I can leave with this). But then, **I release the mouse button** and move it out the iframe... and as soon the mouse touch the div **repeat: without the mouse button pressed** the drag remains active.

It is a bug or a feature of the drag method? 
How can I force to stop the drag behavior? If you try it, youll notice it is a very annoying behavior.

TIA,

Answer (score 0):

It's probably the case that any mouse events over the iframe aren't bubbling up to the parent document.  Basically, when you release the mouse button, that event never makes it back to the draggable handler - it has no way of knowing that you don't have the mouse button pressed anymore.

You could use the draggable "helper" option to replace the iframe with a placeholder div while dragging - alternatively, you could cover the iframe with a transparent overlay while dragging.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I didnt hear about the helper; ill try but without success. But that takes me to other option: iframeFix, that looks to be what I need.

Comment: sadly, iframeFix lock the click property from the element when is over another iframe. Still researching...